# Two different fonts in same table

Tags: tables, fonts

My goal is to use on the left side the PCR font and on the right side it should be the normal font (for example, ssfamily font). Is this possible without using XeTeX? If you ask yourself why this is necessary, I want on the left-hand side (commands/functions) on the right side a description, without always using `\texttt{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, marginparwidth=2cm, headsep=1.2cm]{geometry} % layout

\begin{document}
% ....
\begin{table}[ht!]
 \fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
  \textbf{Function} & \textbf{Meaning} \\
\hline
asdf & ATFD is more than a few\\
Class that is large and complex & WMC is high\\
Class that has a lot of methods that only operate on a proper subset of the instance variable set & TCC is low\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (instead of changing the fontsize as in the linked duplicate, you can just as well change the fontfamily)

Comment: This example is good to know, but it does not help me since I need to have the width of the column and the width of the page. I will search for another solution but thank you!

Comment: It works the very same way in your table: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}X>{\sffamily}X}`

Comment: I just had now the same solution! Perfect! I will directly post my solution :-)

Comment: Rather than post your solution, your question should be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

This works flawlessly

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, marginparwidth=2cm, headsep=1.2cm]{geometry} % layout

\begin{document}
% ....
\begin{table}[ht!]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\ttfamily}X X}
  \textbf{Function} & \textbf{Meaning} \\
\hline
asdf & ATFD is more than a few\\
Class that is large and complex & WMC is high\\
Class that has a lot of methods that only operate on a proper subset of the instance variable set & TCC is low\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```